# Getting a result from a query and returning a value? PHP & MySQLi

Tags: php, database, mysqli, associative-array

When I click submit, the input validation works, but even when I type in the username and password correctly that is stored in my database exactly as I'm entering it, with consideration of the hash, but all I get is the error message telling me the combination is incorrect.

This is my login script:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']) === true) {

$login = login($username, $password);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = "Please fill in all fields";
} elseif ($login === false) {
    $errors[] = "That username and password combination is incorrect";
} else {
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    echo 'Logged in';
}
}
```

And here are the functions:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT userId FROM users where userName = '$username' AND userPass = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($row_count >= 1) {
        return $query['userId'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzntU.png)

Comment: Yeah still doesn't work :/

Comment: why do you even have function getUserId? you're not using that information at all. I mean you are, but you're calling it later. just return $query['userId']

Comment: Shouldn't `$user_id = $get_user_id['user_id'];` be `$user_id = $get_user_id['userId'];`

Comment: @AndrewWilson doesnt the value get returned so that when I set the session the value is the user id for later use

Comment: @SamLane yes, but aren't you requesting that same information in your validation process?

Comment: @dstudeba just changed it and still got the same issue, so the problem must be being caused somewhere else, although thankyou for that.

Comment: can you run 'show create table users' in your db and show the results in ur question?

Comment: @Bizmate yeah just added the image

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest you try is to manually compare the md5 hashed password to what's strutted in the table. If you're absolutely sure they're equal, run a manual query using that value from toad or phpmyadmin and see if you get a result. If not the problem could be in the query. If you get a result check your mysqli_num_rows function and instead of returning the user id echo it in your test environment.

What else have you done to debug?

Comment: The query works in PhpMyAdmin and tried returning true without searching for the userId and still same issue

Comment: In that case debug the mysqli_num_rows statement echo it and see what it's returning

Comment: I just tried it and I'm not getting anything returned, does this mean it isnt working, if it was 0 rows would it display 0?

Comment: Remove the connection variable from the mysqli_num_rows function. You only need to feed it the result argument

Comment: Debug the result by echoing the query string and the mysqli_error

Comment: I just tried this and it gave me SELECT userId FROM users where userName = 'samlane' AND userPass = ''

Comment: So the password isnt being captured?

Comment: Yep, so debug that by echoing the md5 hashed password

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it down to this, however I would not recommend taking user input without XSS scrubbing it. Especially for a table such as login.

```
function login($username, $password) {
    global $conn;
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT userId FROM users where userName = '$username' AND userPass = '$password' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($row_count >= 1) {
        return $query['userId'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense thankyou but its still the same issue, ive removed the get user id function completely and used your code but the issue is still the same, the query works manually in phpmyadmin, to make it easier ive also stored it as a plain text password for now. There is also no sanitization because I figured id get it working first then add it. Ill update the code now

Comment: can you var_dump($result) and put it here? Also are you verifying that your `md5($password)` is the same as your database's value?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code needs some fixes since your checking the parameters if they are empty after you query it to the database, getting the userID before checking if his password is correct.. and so on..

But first, after the line

```
    $query = "SELECT userId FROM users where userName = '$username' AND      userPass = '$password'";
```

why don't u put

```
die($query);
```

run the page, copy the result, paste it into phpMyAdmin query box, and see if the result fits your needs.